# android parse, how to find other username?

Tags: android, parse-platform

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
                query.whereEqualTo("username", "female");
                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username Found",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username Not Found",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });'
```

I have problem with these code, i want to search other username, please help me.
I already write the code but always get in "Username found" but in database there no name like that.

Answer (score 2):

You are wrong because, into **findInBackground** callback, you currently check only the *e* variable (if it is null or not) and not the **objects** size. Exception **is alwasy null** if the query return a valid result from Cloud Code (in this case the object is not null and it size is 0 or greather than); exception variable is valorized **only** if the execution of query raise an exception/error.

To check if a query returns a records or not you must to check the size of objects (List):

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
            query.whereEqualTo("username", "female");
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        if (objects.size() > 0) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username Found",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username Not Found",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "An error has occurred!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Take in consideration the opportunity to limit the query to 1 result (if you looking for one specific record) or use **getFirstInBackground** method to improve query performance.

Comment: Bro 1 more question
how if i want get the "username"?. ty

Comment: objects is a List of ParseUser object; findInBackground returns a list of objects, you need to access to each object by index before retrieve the username parameter: .get(i).getString("username");.